# Why api calls aren't working at gh-pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, github

I just finished writing my weather App and while running on localhost eveything is working perfect as i expected but after i published  it at gh-pages it returns error after API call is done , here is link:

https://jake-j.github.io/weatherAPP/

can someone help me fix that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are hosting your application under https (secured http) and calling API under http (non secured http).

This is not allowed to call resources under non-secured http on secured https sites. You will receive [Mixed Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/) error and loading the resource will be blocked.

You can debug it for example under Network tab in [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) avaliable under <kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut.

The API you are trying to use is available under https, so you can simply fix this issue replacing API call from http:// to https://